# How to change an existing character to a different word when extracting substring into new column?

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I'm using Oracle.

If I have an address like the following:

```
| address             | 
| ------————————————— |
| 1234 SMITH AVE #220 |
```

How do I change the `#` to say `STE` in my output?

My current code is:

```
CASE 
    WHEN database.table.address LIKE '%#%'
        THEN SUBSTR(database.table.address, DECODE(INSTR(database.table.address, '#'), 0, NULL, INSTR,(database.table.address, '#')))
END "address line 2"

CASE 
    WHEN database.table.address LIKE '%#%'
        THEN SUBSTR(database.table.address, 0, INSTR(database.table.address, '#') - 1)
END "address line 1"
```

With my current output being:

```
| address line 1 | address line 2 |
| ------———————- | ----————————-- |
| 1234 SMITH AVE | #220           |
```

My desired output is:

```
| address line 1 | address line 2 |
| ------———————- | ----————————-- |
| 1234 SMITH AVE | STE 220        |
```

Is this possible? I can't seem to figure out how to work it into my existing code. I'm cleaning up an entire dataset of addresses so I can't reference this row of data specifically, it just has to reference the entire column and pull any matches.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use combination of substr + instr.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (address) as
  2    (select ' 1234 SMITH AVE #220' from dual)
```

Query:

```
  3  select trim(substr(address, 1, instr(address, '#') - 1)) line_1,
  4         replace(substr(address, instr(address, '#')), '#', 'STE ') line_2
  5  from test;

LINE_1         LINE_2
-------------- -------
1234 SMITH AVE STE 220

SQL>
```

Though, you didn't say what you want to do if there's NO `#` character in `address`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take your code and instead of starting line 2 from the `#` character, start from the character afterwards and concatenate `'STE '` before it.

So taking your code and simplifying it slightly:

```sql
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN t.address LIKE '%#%'
       THEN SUBSTR(t.address, 1, INSTR(t.address, '#') - 1)
       ELSE t.address
       END AS "address line 1",
       CASE 
       WHEN t.address LIKE '%#%'
       THEN 'STE ' || SUBSTR(t.address, INSTR(t.address, '#') + 1)
       ELSE NULL
       END AS "address line 2"
FROM   database.table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE database.table_name (address) AS
SELECT '1234 SMITH AVE #220' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| address line 1 | address line 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 SMITH AVE | STE 220 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xi1PImmP)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to replace the '#' symbol with 'STE' in the address column. You can achieve this using the REPLACE function. Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN address LIKE '%#%'
    THEN REPLACE(address, '#', 'STE')
    ELSE address
  END AS "address line 1",
  
  CASE
    WHEN address LIKE '%#%'
    THEN SUBSTR(address, INSTR(address, '#') + 1)
    ELSE NULL
  END AS "address line 2"
FROM database.table;
```

Comment: This piece of code returns "1234 SMITH AVE STE220" as 1st line and "220" as 2nd line.